# Quarkus Opentelemetry HTTP span names

Tags: java, rest, http, quarkus, open-telemetry

I am using opentelemetry with Quarkus 2.13.x for telemetry of our microservices. One of the issues i am experiencing is the HTTP REST request randomly captures the span id as PUT or POST based on the type of the operation. The WithSpan annotation on the REST service method just adds another span but doesn't really change the name of the HTTP span. Any idea how i can change the name from PUT/POST to something more application specific?

Also sometimes the name of the main operation shown in Jaeger changes to something different. Instead of showing the first/top span id, it shows a random span id from the list. Is there some threading issue processing the requests? For e.g, the operation is getAllUsers which has a call to get from the DB, the span list shows the DB span id at the top as opposed to getAllUsers.

Thank you in advance

SG

Answer (score 0):

On Quarkus 2.13.x some rest endpoint names are not part of the span name. This and some issues with `http.route` attribute reporting was fixed on Quarkus 3.2.3+.

About the duplicated span: Quarkus will create a span automatically when it receives a REST request. When you use `@WithSpan` on a method, it will always create a new span from that point. This is why you get 2 spans in the end.
If it helps, you can add additional data to the existing span at any point by retrieving it and add data to it.

```java
    Span span = Span.current()
    try(Scope scope = span.makeCurrent()) {
      span.setAttribute("your.atribute.name", "your data");
      ...
    }
```

In relation to Jaeger I'm not sure.